# Должно ли отслеживаться в js нажатие на  кнопку, находящуюся в модальном окне?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

На странице есть кнопка, отслеживаю нажатие на нее через jquery, 
все гуд, отправляю ajax-запрос на php-скрипт, результаты отображаются в div, как html.
В скрипте идет вызов модального окна, где есть кнопка. 
 Вот в чем вопрос: должно ли отслеживаться в js нажатие на эту кнопку, которая в модальном окне?

Answer (score 1):

[[@kke](/users/24972/kke)](/users/24972/kke), Если модальное окно подгружено динамически, то будет отслеживаться при делегированной обработке событий.